# mysql: How can I remove character at start or end of field

Tags: mysql, replace

I have field that contains a comma-separated list. Some old records have a comma at the beginning or end of the field. I need to remove these extra commas.

Example:

`,the,their,then` to `the,their,then`

or

`the,their,then,` to `the,their,then`

EDIT: I am looking for an UPDATE statement. I need to change the records.

Comment: Is this for a SELECT or an UPDATE statement?

Comment: It is for UPDATE. I need to remove them.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Check [this](http://www.mydigitallife.info/remove-or-trim-first-or-last-few-characters-in-mysql-database-with-sql/) website

```
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING 'xyz' FROM 'barxxyz');
```

which in your case would be ',' instead of 'xyz'

Comment: This will return the values with the trailing comma removed, but it won't modify the database. They'd need to use TRIM() in an update statement for that.

Comment: Are those "smart quotes" valid syntax?

Answer (score 30):

@codingbiz, Thank you for the website link:

Quick examples:

```
SELECT TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM fieldname) from tablename

SELECT TRIM(LEADING ',' FROM fieldname) from tablename

SELECT TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM fieldname) from tablename
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

The question was how to remove the leading and trailing characters I will show you an example with an update query.

```
UPDATE your_table_name
SET your_record_name = TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM your_record_name)
```

Comment: This one is actually correct, as it actually provides a working UPDATE statement.

Comment: perfect answer !

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [`TRIM` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_trim).

Answer (score 1):

To avoid other tables getting affected you should use a where clause. These will only update the rows with trailing ','

```
UPDATE table_name 
set field_name = TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM field_name)
WHERE field_name LIKE '%,';
```

Not putting where clause affected my rows with Null Values and made them empty strings